libreoffice conversion in express
im currently trying to convert different files like, music, videos,image and this 3 work fine but when i try to convert documents using libreoffice in my express server
some of them are successfully converted but if it is not successful this error always
show.
Conversion error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\libreofficeConvert_-27920-NNg4r8O5ucJU\source.fodt'

for example
html - doc,docx,rtf,ods,xlsx,xlscsv,odp,ppt,pptx,xml,epub,mml,fodt this shows that error and others like pdf to other format it shows same error
this are myy example code
    const express = require("express");
const libre = require("libreoffice-convert");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const tempDir = path.join(__dirname, "temp");
if (!fs.existsSync(tempDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(tempDir);
}
process.env.TMPDIR = tempDir;

const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

const deleteFile = (filePath) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
      console.log(`File deleted successfully: ${filePath}`);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error deleting file ${filePath}:`, err);
    }
  }, 1000);
};

// Document Conversion Endpoint
app.post("/convert-document", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  const inputPath = req.file.path;
  const outputFormat = req.body.format || ".pdf";
  const outputPath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    "uploads",
    `${req.file.filename}${outputFormat}`,
  );

  console.log(`Starting conversion: ${inputPath} to ${outputPath}`);
  console.log(`Temporary directory: ${process.env.TMPDIR}`);

  if (!fs.existsSync(inputPath)) {
    console.error("Input file does not exist.");
    return res.status(400).send("Input file does not exist.");
  }

  const file = fs.readFileSync(inputPath);
  libre.convert(file, outputFormat, undefined, (err, done) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Conversion error: ${err.message}`);
      return res.status(500).send(`Conversion error: ${err.message}`);
    }

    console.log(`Conversion successful: ${inputPath} to ${outputPath}`);
    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, done);
    res.download(outputPath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error sending file:", err);
      }
      // Clean up input and output files
      deleteFile(inputPath);
      deleteFile(outputPath);
    });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

i already add the environmental varaible in path

C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program

when conversion is successful in other format this log in my express

0|coverter-server  | Starting conversion:
uploads\aa4a02556987e78d1a4583c88da78f49 to
C:\xampp\htdocs\ConverteVue\src\express-server\uploads\aa4a02556987e78d1a4583c88da78f49html
0|coverter-server  | Temporary directory:
C:\xampp\htdocs\ConverteVue\src\express-server\temp 0|coverter-server
| Conversion successful: uploads\aa4a02556987e78d1a4583c88da78f49 to
C:\xampp\htdocs\ConverteVue\src\express-server\uploads\aa4a02556987e78d1a4583c88da78f49html
0|coverter-server  | File deleted successfully:
uploads\aa4a02556987e78d1a4583c88da78f49 0|coverter-server  | File
deleted successfully:
C:\xampp\htdocs\ConverteVue\src\express-server\uploads\aa4a02556987e78d1a4583c88da78f49html

if not this shows

0|coverter-server  | Starting conversion:
uploads\615178f63b74e3f349dae22eb184cd95 to
C:\xampp\htdocs\ConverteVue\src\express-server\uploads\615178f63b74e3f349dae22eb184cd95ods
0|coverter-server  | Temporary directory:
C:\xampp\htdocs\ConverteVue\src\express-server\temp 0|coverter-server
| Conversion error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\libreofficeConvert_-27920-hj0lebIxy5v4\source.ods'

